# RserveException: eval failed when running R on Databricks

Tags: r, apache-spark

I don't have any experience with R and I'm trying to use it in a Databricks notebook together with Spark to analyse some data.

I have followed the tutorial from here http://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-releases/latest/sparkr.html

So far I have this code:

```
sparkR.stop()
sc <- sparkR.init()
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, '/FileStore/tables/boanf7gu1466936449434/german.data')
```

On the last line I am getting the error:

```
RserveException: eval failed, request status: error code: 127
org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: eval failed, request status: error code: 127
    at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.eval(RConnection.java:234)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.RShell.setJobGroup(RShell.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.RDriverLocal.setJobGroup(RDriverLocal.scala:150)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:125)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$3.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:483)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$3.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:483)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:480)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:381)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:212)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What triggers this?

Comment: It should probably go to Databricks support support. As far as I am concerned creating custom context is not supported there but I could be wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by custom context?

Comment: I mean you're stopping provided context and creating new one.

Answer (score 0):

In DataBricks, there is already a spark instance running. So, you don't want to stop it.

```
sparkR.stop() #This line of your code stops the existing spark instance. 
sc <- sparkR.init()  #You also don't need this to start a spark instance because you already have one.
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
```

Since you already have an instance, you can create your df directly with the below.

```
spark_table <- SparkR::read.df(path = '/FileStore/tables/boanf7gu1466936449434/german.data', schema = NULL, na.strings = "NA")
r_table <- SparkR::as.data.frame(spark_table)
```